# Angulrar formly fieldGroup is not working for field with key as integer

Tags: angular, angular-formly, ngx-formly

Angular formly fieldGroup should the object but it is returning the array as value.

as per formly field config, inventories property in model object should be in object but it is giving array.

package.json

```
    "@ngx-formly/bootstrap": "^6.1.2",
    "@ngx-formly/core": "^6.1.2",
```

app.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
  <formly-form
    [model]="model"
    [fields]="fields"
    [options]="options"
    [form]="form"
  ></formly-form>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit-button">Submit</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="options.resetModel()">
    Reset
  </button>
</form>

<p>{{ model | json }}</p>
<!-- Copyright 2021 Formly. All Rights Reserved.
    Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
    can be found in the LICENSE file at https://github.com/ngx-formly/ngx-formly/blob/main/LICENSE -->
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormlyFormOptions, FormlyFieldConfig } from '@ngx-formly/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'formly-app-example',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {
  form = new FormGroup({});
  model: any = {};
  options: FormlyFormOptions = {
    formState: {
      awesomeIsForced: false,
    },
  };

  fields: FormlyFieldConfig[] = [
    {
      key: 'inventories',
      fieldGroup: [
        {
          key: '3',
          type: 'input',
          props: {
            label: 'Text',
            placeholder: 'Formly field 3',
            required: true,
          },
        },
        {
          key: '4',
          type: 'input',
          props: {
            label: 'Text',
            placeholder: 'Formly field 3',
            required: true,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  ];

  submit() {
    if (this.form.valid) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(this.model));
    }
  }
}
```

below is OutPut of model from above code ( looks like error)

```
{ "inventories": [ null, null, null, "22", "33" ] }
```

Expected output for form model.

```
{ 
  "inventories": {"3": "22", "4": "33" } 
}
```

Comment: is any change required to code for this.

Comment: will you be able to share entire fields information. As key having number, seems formly sorting it.

Comment: @Dayananda i have mentoned field config above, let me know if anything else is required from me.

Comment: Could you please provide a reproducible example of your issue on https://codesandbox.io/. This will allow the community to better understand the specific challenges you're facing and offer more targeted assistance.

Comment: @Webia1
please find the link bellow.  
[https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b43wet-e1tsxk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b43wet-e1tsxk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)  

check the output provided by formly  
```
{
  "inventories": [
    null,
    null,
    null,
    "field 3",
    "field 4"
  ]
}
```
  
but it should be this


```
{ 
  "inventories": {"3": "22", "4": "33" } 
}
```

Comment: here you go: https://angular-b43wet-dmkalu.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 0):

Some minor adjustments are required:

1. Begin by adding a suitable type definition for the model:

```
export type FormModel = {
  inventories: {
    [index: number | string]: string;
  };
};
```

2. Next, make a slight modification to your method:

```
  changeModel() {
    this.model = {
      inventories: {
        text: 'new text',
      },
    };
  }
```

[>> See Stackblitz Example Online](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b43wet-dmkalu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Update your submit function.

```
submit() {
  if (this.form.valid) {
    const inventoriesObj = this.model.inventories.reduce((acc, value, index) => {
      acc[index + 3] = value;
      return acc;
    }, {});

    this.model.inventories = inventoriesObj;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.model);)

    //alert(JSON.stringify(this.model));
  }
}
```

Try this and let me know how it works